# Calculation loop in python new values

Tags: python, loops

I would like to do the calculation loop using my function.

```
b=list(data.iloc[1])

def balance(rate, payment, os):
    interest_amount=os*rate/100/12
    principal_amount=payment-interest_amount    
    next_balance=os+interest_amount-principal_amount
    return next_balance

c=balance(b[9], b[11], b[8])
d=balance(b[9], b[11], c)
e=balance(b[9], b[11], d)
```

I would have to start with `b[8]` as the amount for calculation. After I got the next amount from the function `balance`, the next amount will be the beginning of the third calculation and so on until the next amount eqaul of less than 0. It should stop the loop.

I need to append calculated values since `b[8]` until the last (before getting 0 or less).

Any suggestion on this, thank you!

Edit: based on Zaraki Kenpachi

`b[8]` is amount of money given 17183
`b[9]` is rate of interest given 3.39
`b[11]` is payment per month given 5759

The output, which I am trying to do is:

```
[17183, 11,521, 5,826, 99]
```

Comment: Chalyadecha show you `b` list and desired output.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Already added

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
x = b[8]
output = []
output.append(x)
while x > 0:
    x = balance(b[9], b[11], X)
    output.append(x)
```

Comment: No, the next balance should be replaced with new calculated values from the first loop

Comment: It does that, see that x is set to the new balance

Comment: yes, my bad! so sorry. I do the manual calculation, your results is correct. The only problem is when I added it my loop, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
def balance(rate, payment, os):
    interest_amount=os*rate/100/12
    principal_amount=payment-interest_amount
    next_balance=os+interest_amount-principal_amount
    return next_balance


next_balance = 17183 # = b[8]
results = []
results.append(next_balance)
while next_balance > 0:
    next_balance = balance(3.39, 5759, next_balance) # b[9], b[11]
    if next_balance > 0:
        results.append(next_balance)
```

**Output:**

```
[17183, 11521.08395, 5827.1780743175, 101.10163043739522]
```

Comment: No, the next balance should be replaced with new calculated values from the first loop

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha it is done with while loop. first `next_balance = 17183`, second is from while loop `next_balance = balance(3.39, 5759, next_balance)` and so on until `next_balance > 0`. Compare results with you manual calculations. You output list is not correct.

Comment: @ ZarakiKenpachi yes, my bad! so sorry. I do the manual calculation, your results is correct. The only problem is when I added it my loop, it doesn't work.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha what you mean by : `I added it my loop, it doesn't work`? You need to set `next_balance = b[8]` replace:`3.39->b[9], 5759->b[11]`

Comment: nope! I have more than one calculation and need to do case by case. So I add checking condition before your code. It doesn't work more than 1 loop 'for i in range(0, 2):
    a=list(exclusion1.iloc[i])
    if a[6]<3 and a[10]>=1:
        x=a[8]
        amortization=[]
        amortization.append(x)
        
        while x>0:
            x=balance(a[9], a[11], x)
            amortization.append(x)'

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha then post you `data`. I don't know what you have inside

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a builtin way to [unfold](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) / [iterate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) but the normal way you'd implenent a specific unfold is through a *generator*, which can keep computational state and yield values:

```py
def balances(balance, rate, payment):
    while True:
        interest_amount = balance*rate/100/12
        principal_amount = payment-interest_amount    
        balance = os+interest_amount-principal_amount
        # TO DO: end the computation when balance <= 0, maybe find a way to 
        # note extra in the last payment, or reject the last payment entirely
        # and handle that case separately outside the generator
        yield balance
```

then you can either call `next()` on your balances iterator to get successive values

```py
bs = balances(b[8], b[9], b[11])
c = next(bs)
d = next(bs)
e = next(bs)
```

or iterate the entire thing

```py
for balance in balances(b[8], b[9], b[11]):
    if balance < 0: 
        "do something when the last payment was excessive and stop the loop"
    ...
```